# IndexOutOfBoundsException in Mahout

Tags: java, mahout

I'm trying to run mahout SGD classifier on a CSV file, and I'm getting this error -

```
 
[vineet@localhost bin]$ ./mahout trainlogistic --input ./filtered.csv --output model --target target --categories 33 \
--features 200 --passes 10 --predictors subject --types text --rate 50
```

hadoop binary is not in PATH,HADOOP_HOME/bin,HADOOP_PREFIX/bin, running locally
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 4
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.CsvRecordFactory.processLine(CsvRecordFactory.java:245)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.TrainLogistic.mainToOutput(TrainLogistic.java:85)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.TrainLogistic.main(TrainLogistic.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
        at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)

The CSV file contains unicode text, and large text fields enclosed by quote characters.

I've tried the classifier on the sample donut.csv, and it works fine.
I also tried changing my header row to make it like "id","subject","field2",etc.., but it still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are fetching the Index: 6, Size: 4.

Comment: Yes, but I couldnt make any sense of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some lines may dirty - only have 4 attributes instead of 6. check your data again or try to feed only one line of data to validate my guess.

Comment: that helped me solve the issue - it seems mahout didnt like that I had  an empty field at the end.. thanks!